# Estimated Operator Cost Calculation

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

Everywhere I have read says that the Estimated Operator Cost is the sum of the Estimated CPU Cost and the and the Estimated I/O Cost. However, in many operators I see, this is not the case. Here is an example:

```
SELECT Column2
INTO   Object1
FROM   Object2
WHERE  Column3 >= Variable2
       AND Column3 <= Variable1
       AND ( Column4 = Variable5
              OR Variable5 = ? )
```

[image]

EstimateIO="0.01" 
EstimateCPU="0.000246492"

Sum: 0.010246492

Yet SSMS shows this 0.073823 as the Estimated Operator Cost. I am at a complete loss as to how this is getting calculated. Below is the execution plan xml (anonymized). Node Id 0 is the node in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.6537.0">
    <BatchSequence>
        <Batch>
            <Statements>
                <StmtSimple StatementText="&#x9;SELECT Column2 INTO Object1 &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;FROM Object2&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;WHERE Column3&gt;=Variable2 AND Column3&lt;=Variable1 &#xD;&#xA;&#x9;AND (Column4=Variable5 OR Variable5=?)&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;" StatementId="1" StatementCompId="7" StatementType="SELECT INTO" RetrievedFromCache="true" StatementSubTreeCost="0.405134" StatementEstRows="246.492" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" QueryHash="0x180DF38DFFFEAFA2" QueryPlanHash="0x45A4295471B90968" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound">
                    <StatementSetOptions QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" ARITHABORT="false" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" />
                    <QueryPlan CachedPlanSize="48" CompileTime="23" CompileCPU="6" CompileMemory="360">
                        <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
                        <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="157286" EstimatedPagesCached="314572" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="16" />
                        <RelOp NodeId="0" PhysicalOp="Table Insert" LogicalOp="Insert" EstimateRows="246.492" EstimateIO="0.01" EstimateCPU="0.000246492" AvgRowSize="9" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.405134" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row">
                            <OutputList />
                            <Update DMLRequestSort="0">
                                <Object Table="Object1" />
                                <SetPredicate>
                                    <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString1">
                                        <ScalarExpressionList>
                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                                <MultipleAssign>
                                                    <Assign>
                                                        <ColumnReference Table="Object1" Column="Column2" />
                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                            <Identifier>
                                                                <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column2" />
                                                            </Identifier>
                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Assign>
                                                </MultipleAssign>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                        </ScalarExpressionList>
                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                </SetPredicate>
                                <RelOp NodeId="1" PhysicalOp="Index Seek" LogicalOp="Index Seek" EstimateRows="246.492" EstimateIO="0.22831" EstimateCPU="0.103001" AvgRowSize="15" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.331311" TableCardinality="1.03883e+006" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row">
                                    <OutputList>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column2" />
                                    </OutputList>
                                    <IndexScan Ordered="1" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="0" ForceSeek="0" ForceScan="0" NoExpandHint="0" Storage="RowStore">
                                        <DefinedValues>
                                            <DefinedValue>
                                                <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column2" />
                                            </DefinedValue>
                                        </DefinedValues>
                                        <Object Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Index="Index1" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                                        <SeekPredicates>
                                            <SeekPredicateNew>
                                                <SeekKeys>
                                                    <StartRange ScanType="GE">
                                                        <RangeColumns>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column3" />
                                                        </RangeColumns>
                                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString2">
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Column="Column7" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                                    </StartRange>
                                                    <EndRange ScanType="LE">
                                                        <RangeColumns>
                                                            <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column3" />
                                                        </RangeColumns>
                                                        <RangeExpressions>
                                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString3">
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Column="Column8" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </RangeExpressions>
                                                    </EndRange>
                                                </SeekKeys>
                                            </SeekPredicateNew>
                                        </SeekPredicates>
                                        <Predicate>
                                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ScalarString4">
                                                <Logical Operation="OR">
                                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Database="Database1" Schema="Schema1" Table="Object2" Column="Column4" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                            <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                    <ColumnReference Column="Column9" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </Compare>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                    <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                            <ColumnReference Column="Column10">
                                                                <ScalarOperator>
                                                                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Identifier>
                                                                                <ColumnReference Column="Column9" />
                                                                            </Identifier>
                                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                                        <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Const ConstValue="Value4" />
                                                                        </ScalarOperator>
                                                                    </Compare>
                                                                </ScalarOperator>
                                                            </ColumnReference>
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                    </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Logical>
                                            </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Predicate>
                                    </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                            </Update>
                        </RelOp>
                        <ParameterList>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Column9" ParameterCompiledValue="Value1" />
                        </ParameterList>
                    </QueryPlan>
                </StmtSimple>
            </Statements>
        </Batch>
    </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

EDIT: Realized I did not post a well formulated question. Here is the question:

Given the example plan, what formula or calculation did SSMS and Plan Explorer use to arrive at the Estimated Operator Cost of 0.073823 for Node 0?

Comment: SQL Sentry plan explorer shows different results http://i.stack.imgur.com/uEo3m.png - looks like they must adjust the values to make them consistent.

Comment: Yea, I use Plan Explorer as well Martin and saw that. So I am very curious, how did they calculate that? It looks like the I/O cost was adjusted in Plan Explorer. Then plan explorer shows the same exact Estimated Operator Cost.  

How did Plan Explorer make the change to the I/O cost that resulted in the proper Operator Cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grant, I believe a coworker (Dennis Rogers) and I have answered the question. Here appears the definitive formula that SSMS uses to calc the operator cost and the cost %.

Estimated Operator Cost == @EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost - Sum(Immediate Children@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost)

Estimated Operator Cost Percent = Estimated Operator Cost / StmtSimple@StatementSubTreeCost * 100

I have tested this out with several plans and this appears to be spot on.

To represent the above calculation as xpath it turns into:

```
@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost - sum(./descendant::s:RelOp[1]/../s:RelOp/@EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost)
```

The sum finds the first descendant that is of type RelOp, then backs up one level, and gets all of the RelOps at that level and extracts their EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost.

Comment: If this is true, then why can SSMS report childless operators as having over 100% cost? [Example](https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/18056-part-of-query-plan.png?platform=QnA).

Answer (score 3):

The only way to properly answer that question is to fire up the debugger and see what choices were made by the optimizer along the way. The costs are not only IO and CPU. There are additional costs associated with a given operator that are reflected in the total cost, but are not reflected in the IO and CPU cost estimates. You can read more about some of the additional costs in this [excellent article by Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/09/inside-the-optimizer-plan-costing.html).

I don't have a precise answer to your question (I've not doubt, Paul would). However, I'm willing to take a guess. What you're seeing is added overhead for the operation as determined by the optimizer above and beyond what it is displaying as the overhead for the IO and CPU as determined by the estimated rows, etc.. I believe it's a calculation based on what would necessary in terms of IO to create the table and store the 246.492 rows * 9b worth of data on each that is calculated as being in the INSERT statement. 246.492 * 9 / 1024 = 2.1664 is less than an 8k page. However, we have to create at least a page, so when you calculate 8 * the cost of .01, it puts us just a little above the estimated .073832. That's my guess, and it is a guess. However, I do know that there is overhead in the costs that isn't displayed by the strict addition of CPU + IO in all cases.