# Sort execution plan XML by estimated operator cost

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

I want to sort execution plan XML by **Estimated Operator Cost**, but the problem is:

SQL Server execution plan has the "Estimated Operator Cost" entry in UI:

[image]

...but that value is missing from the XML output.

There are several suggestions on how to sort the XML, like:

- [SQL Server – Find the most expensive operations in Execution plans](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/2010/01/21/sql-server-ndash-find-the-most-expensive-operations-in-execution/) by Mladen Prajdić.
- [How to find the most expensive operation in an execution plan](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2819f64c-2272-4a15-9b9d-8ce643285aa6/how-to-find-the-most-expensive-operation-in-an-execution-plan-need-to-read-xml-and-sort-on?forum=transactsql) on the old MSDN forums.

But neither are even close to what I'm having, as the "Estimated Operator Cost" seems to be [a super complicated calculation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143548/estimated-operator-cost-calculation).

Is there any solution to this problem please?

Comment: Please share an execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We can't work with pictures. Please also add expected output

Answer (score 7):

### nope

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this, since cost is always an estimate, and [quite prone to being incorrect](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/plan-cache-liars/signs-your-execution-plan-is-lying-to-you-operator-costs/) as far as what the most time consuming portion of a query is.

At this point, cost is considered a [unitless metric](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/why-you-should-stop-looking-at-query-cost/) -- you may come across the phrase query bucks in your travels -- there's no "[actual cost](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/is-it-time-to-remove-costs-from-query-plans/)" even in actual query plans.

If your plan is to dig through the plan cache for comparatively expensive operators, your better bet is to sort plans by a more useful metric like [average cpu](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/sp_blitzcache-the-law-of-averages/). That at least gives you some idea what ran for a long time.

If you just want to examine one query, your best bet is to get the actual execution plan and look at [operator times](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLX25yBff3g) to figure out which part ran slowly.

That can get annoying with larger stored procs, which may be easier to observe with [Extended Events](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_humanevents/), or just look at plans for [specific queries](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/getting-specific-query-plans-from-stored-procedures/) in, if you have some idea which ones are running poorly.